# C# 6.0 - Unexpected character '$'

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

I'm new to programming and I have just installed Visual Studio 2017. I created this code (from the book I'm learning), but this does not compile. I have problem with string interpolation and I get error:

> Unexpected character '$',

but I'm using C# 6.0 so this should not be a problem ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
{   
     string comparison;   
     WriteLine("Enter the number:");   
     double var1 = ToDouble(ReadLine());   
     WriteLine("Enter another number :");   
     double var2 = ToDouble(ReadLine());   
     if (var1 < var2)   
         comparison = "less than";   
     else   
     {   
         if (var1 == var2)   
             comparison = "equal to";   
         else   
             comparison = "greater than";    
      }   

     WriteLine($ "The first number is {comparison} the second number");
     ReadKey();   
}
```

Comment: Even though this is only a problem of spacing I disagree on it being on hold for this reason. This resulted in a compilation error that seems strange at first as spacing is not an issue in many parts of C#

Answer (score 12):

It is a very small problem :) Remove space after `$`:

```
WriteLine($"The first number is {comparison} the second number");
```

See proper structure under [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings#comments-container):

```
$"<text> {<interpolated-expression> [,<field-width>] [:<format-string>] } <text> ..."
```

I've requested an edit that explains that there must be no spacing after the `$` and now it states:

[image]